# Swapping the variables using pointers. What is the difference? (C Programming)

Tags: c, pointers, variables, swap

What is the difference between the two functions? Can you show that through an example? Thank you in advance.

One is swapping variables using variables, the other one is doing the same thing just with pointers. I am given that one of them is wrong, but which one and why?

```html
void swap1(int x, int y) {
  int temp;
  
  temp = x;
  x = y;
  y = temp;
}


void swap2(int *p1, int *p2) {
  int temp;
  
  temp = *p1;
  *p1 = *p2;
  *p2 = temp;
}
```

Comment: Those are from K&R aren't they? Isn't it explained immediately after that in the text?

Comment: Read a good book about C programming such as [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/). Basically an entire book is needed to answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the concepts of pointers. Consider the program below (just added some informative code):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap1(int x, int y) {
    printf("swap1 : xaddr = %p yaddr = %p\n", &x, &y);

    printf("swap1: %d %d\n", x, y);

    int temp;
    temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;

    printf("swap1: %d %d\n", x, y);
}


void swap2(int *p1, int *p2) {
    printf("swap2 : xaddr = %p yaddr = %p\n", p1, p2);

    int temp;
    temp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = temp;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 10, y = 20;

    printf("main: xaddr = %p yaddr = %p\n", &x, &y);

    swap1(x, y);

    printf("main after swap1 : %d %d\n", x, y);

    swap2(&x, &y);

    printf("main after swap2: %d %d\n", x, y);

    return 0;
}
```

The variables `x` and `y` in the main are residing in the local function stack of the `main()`, when `swap1` is called just the copy of the values are passed not the actual address where `x` and `y` are residing. So, swap operation just takes place between the values which are local to `swap1`. Whereas in the case of `swap2`, the actual address is being passed. So any operations you perform on that address is reflected in `main()` also.

Output:

```
main: xaddr = 0x7ffda2efc05c yaddr = 0x7ffda2efc058
swap1 : xaddr = 0x7ffda2efc02c yaddr = 0x7ffda2efc028
swap1: 10 20
swap1: 20 10
main after swap1 : 10 20
swap2 : xaddr = 0x7ffda2efc05c yaddr = 0x7ffda2efc058
main after swap2: 20 10
```

It is evident from the output that the address of `x` and `y` in the `main` are different from the `swap1`, and the swap operation indeed took place in `swap1`, but it is just local to `swap1`. Whereas in `swap2`, we are operating on the same address, which `main` treats as `x` and `y`, so operations are permanent.